# Split string, doubles and ints from a string using IndexOf()

Tags: java, string, split, indexof

I want to split strings, ints and doubles from a string.
The string is entered in a textbox and can contain all three. (For example: Hello 13 94 3,2 6.4 bye)
I want to split them and sum them up. Then I want to show them to a label.

So the labels should say:
String: Hello bye
Int: 107
Double: 9,6

Can anyone get me underway? I'm not allowed to use the split function.

Comment: It look like you use both comma and period as decimal mark.

Comment: Try something. Iterate through the chars of the string and end the current word each time you reach a space. Then check if the current word is a double, an int, or a string.

Comment: iterate through characters and use regular expression to identify integer ?[0-9]* , double ?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]* and string ?[a-zA-Z\s]

Answer (score 1):

Well, without split you can just loot through and detect char by char what you are reading. if it has letters, its string, if dot or comma its double. And reset this detection every time you found a space. Thats pretty much all you should need.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I can get going now!

Answer (score 0):

If you only allow the way to specify decimal point according to current locale, then it is possible to use `Scanner` to solve this problem elegantly:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputString);

while (sc.hasNext()) {
    if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
       // It is an integer
       sc.nextInt();
    } else if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
       // It is a double
       sc.nextDouble();
    } else {
       // Neither, so treat it as string
       sc.next();
    }
}
```

Actually, `Scanner` class allows much more flexibility in what constitute a `double`. Check out [the grammar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#number-syntax) in the documentation of Scanner class regarding number syntax.

Note that the tokens must be separated by spaces (as defined by `\p{javaWhitespace}`). It is possible to define different delimiter, but it will need a clear definition of what constitutes a delimiter in your case.

It actually doesn't make much sense to allow both `,` and `.` as decimal separator at the same time. `345,234` is one such example where it is not clear whether the number should be in the hundred thousands or in the hundreds. The user should use the appropriate decimal separator and thousand separator in the `Locale` that their system is on.

Comment: in some countries like Germany they use commas in place of decimal point. hence there might be a need.

Comment: @Jack: I agree about the need, but I disagree about allowing `,` and `.` to be used at the same time with the same meaning (decimal point).